# AWS S3 presign url, check file exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use AWS php SDK.
How can I check if file exist using presign request commands?

Currently I use "GetObject" command but I do not need it download file. I only need check if file exist.

```
$cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => 's3.test.bucket',
        'Key'    => $fileKey
    ]);

    $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+60 minutes')->withMethod('GET');

    return (string)$request->getUri();
```

Is there any command to achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: @Marcin I founded solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. The proper command is `HeadObject` and method is `HEAD`.
Return 200 or 404.